# How to cut high precision inside corners?

Tags: cutting

How can I cut high precision inside corners? By high precision I mean +/- 1/64" or better.

In some rare cases I need to cut L-shaped pieces of wood. This has the tricky problem of cutting the inside corner. Jigsaws and band saws do not make a clean cut to the precision required.

The problem with American miter saws is that often they have that fold of metal over the top edge and that prevents them from make a clean cut or lying flat against the reference surface.

One thing I have not tried is a Japanese saw. That might be the way to do it. Set up a slotted rail jig of some type and use a Japanese saw.

Another idea is to use a scroll saw, but the problem there is that scroll saws are not really intended to make long, straight cuts.

Comment: When you say "American miter saws" are you referring to the powered tool (like a sliding compound miter saw) or the hand tool (a long back saw that fits in a miter box)?  I think you can clarify the question by indicating if you're using hand tools or power tools.  Since I think you're talking about hand tools it's worth pointing out that there are western hand saws without backs (panel saws) or with deeper plates (tenon saws) and there are Japanese saws with backs (dozuki).

Comment: Like most things with hand tools, the best way to do this is probably to get close with the saw and then refine with a hand plane.  Since you're talking about an inside corner you'll need to use some kind of rabbeting plane.

Comment: Knowing the dimensions of the part you want to make would help. I can make a "perfect" 90° inside corner with a router bit or a dado head, and I can get pretty darn close with a rip blade in a table saw, but they all have depth limitations. A well-tuned band saw can do an excellent job, but it'll always have length limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a perfect inside 90 with a saw of any kerf size or the nicest router bit. This is not specific to wood, either. Machinists cannot make a perfect (for them) inside 90 with any tool in metal. It's just the nature of how cutters and cutter geometry work.

Inside corners are always a problem for close fits, and the only solution is to cut some relief into the corner such that any outside 90 that wants to fit into that corner never *quite* meets it. Even CNC or machine cutting will only be able to make so many guarantees about inside corners. They usually recommend you allow for this fact in your fitting by designing relief into mating parts. Most CAD programs can do this automagically for wood or metal.

I recommend doing what old-time cabinet makers do for mortices where the shoulder needs to be right on the money: use a chisel to cut a relief into the corner such that mating surfaces never quite meet at that inside corner. (Obviously, chamfering tenons will also help.)

If this isn't for joinery and you want as perfect as you can get, the recommendation still stands: finish with a chisel (or bullnose or shoulder or chisel plane, or a safe-edge file) and sneak up on it using your best square.